# Update settings of an existing HandsOnTable instance

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I try to update the HandsonTable settings on the fly. The settings seem to update but the rendered table still uses the previous settings.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kAFWA/30/

updateSettings Documentation: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.18.0/Core.html#updateSettings

```js
var ht;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#example1").handsontable({
    minRows: 5,
    minCols: 5,
    colHeaders: ["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"],
    rowHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: {
      items: {
        "edit_Header": {
          name: "Edit this Header!!"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  ht = $('#example1').handsontable("getInstance");
});

function updateContextMenu() {

  console.log(ht);
  ht.updateSettings({
    minRows: 4,
    minCols: 4,
    colHeaders: ["Header 4", "Header 5", "Header 6"],
    contextMenu: {
      items: {
        "edit_Header": {
          name: "Another Text"
        },
      }
    }
  }, true);
  console.log('here');
  ht.render();
}
```

```html
<link href="http://handsontable.com/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://handsontable.com/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<div id="example1" class="handsontable"></div>

<p>
  <button type="button" name="update" title="Update context menu" onclick="updateContextMenu()">Update context menu</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, so you want to get rid of that second argument to your `updateSettings`. Not sure what it does, but if you get rid of it in your fiddle, it updates correctly. Just fyi, no need to re-render since it does that at the end anyways.